# ¿Porqué obtengo este error en mi método de transformación de segmento de cadena?

Tags: c#, string

Estoy escribiendo un método de extensión para el tipo `System.String` llamado `Transform`, que me permite transformar un segmento de cadena delimitado por un rango (`System.Range`).

Acá muestro, a modo de ejemplo, las distintas formas de invocar dicho método:

```
"Hello, World!".Transform(StringTransformation.Normal,             range: 2..8) // Devuelve Hello, World!
"Hello, World!".Transform(StringTransformation.UpperCase,          range: 2..8) // Devuelve HeLLO, WOrld!
"HELLO, WORLD!".Transform(StringTransformation.LowerCase,          range: 2..8) // Devuelve HEllo, woRLD!
"hello, world!".Transform(StringTransformation.Capitalize,         range: 2..8) // Devuelve heLlo, world!
"hello, world!".Transform(StringTransformation.CapitalizeAllWords, range: 2..8) // Error: IndexOutOfRangeException
```

---

El problema reside en que para la lógica de `CapitalizeAllWords`, se me ocurrió capitalizar cada caracter subsecuente a un espacio en blanco, de esta forma:

```
if (char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[i - 1]) && i > 0)
{
    chars[i] = char.ToUpper(chars[i]);
}
```

Pero me genera una `IndexOutOfRangeException`, lo cual no entiendo, ya que en un rango de 2 a 8 restar 1 devuelve posiciones de matriz válidas que no se salen del rango de elementos de dicha matriz.

Quizá hice algo mal y no lo estoy viendo, por lo que si alguien me pudiese ayudar le estaré agradecido.

---

Este es el código de `Transform` que tengo hasta ahora:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Transform(this string source, StringTransformation transformation, System.Range range)
    {
        int     start   = range.Start.Value;
        int     end     = range.End  .Value;
        char[]  chars   = source.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            switch (transformation)
            {
                case StringTransformation.LowerCase:
                
                    chars[i] = char.ToLower(chars[i]);
                
                break;

                case StringTransformation.UpperCase:
                
                    chars[i] = char.ToUpper(chars[i]);

                break;

                case StringTransformation.Capitalize:
                
                    chars[start] = char.ToUpper(chars[start]);

                break;

                case StringTransformation.CapitalizeAllWords:

                    chars[0] = char.ToUpper(chars[0]);

                    if (char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[i - 1]) && i > 0)
                    {
                        chars[i] = char.ToUpper(chars[i]);
                    }

                break;
            }
        }

        // Las cadenas son inmutables
        return new string(chars);
    }
}

public enum StringTransformation
{
    Normal,
    Capitalize,
    CapitalizeAllWords,
    LowerCase,
    UpperCase
}
```

---

El resultado esperado para la opción `CapitalizeAllWords` para una cadena de entrada `hello world!` debería ser `Hello World!` teniendo en cuenta que capitalizo el primer caracter de toda la cadena antes de `if (char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[i - 1]) && i > 0)`.

Comment: Que resultado esperas obtener?

Comment: @Japv para una cadena de entrada `hello, world!` esta opción debería devolver `hello, World!` ya que el índice de inicio 2 apunta a la mitad de la palabra `hello` que es `llo` y eso no es una palabra como tal, en cambio `world` si lo es.

Comment: Eso, ignorando que capitalizo el primer caracter de la cadena de entrada antes del `if (char.IsWhiteSpace(chars[i - 1]) && i > 0)`, si se tiene en cuenta eso entonces el resultado esperado es `Hello, World!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes

**1.- Una función que para transformar un `string`**

Se puede crear una de manera sencilla como:

```
public static string Transform(this string source, StringTransformation transformation)
{
           
    if (source.Length == 0) return source;
    return transformation switch
    {
        StringTransformation.LowerCase => source.ToLower(),
        StringTransformation.UpperCase => source.ToUpper(),
        StringTransformation.Normal => source,
        StringTransformation.Capitalize => char.ToUpper(source[0]) + source[1..],
        StringTransformation.CapitalizeAllWords => CapitalizeAllWords(source),
        _ => source
    };
}

 private static string CapitalizeAllWords(string sourse)
  => string.Join(" ", sourse.Split(" ").Select(a => a.Transform(StringTransformation.Capitalize)));
```

Los primeros 3 casos son obvios, para los otros 2:

- **Capitalize**: Tomamos el primer carácter y lo colocamos en mayúsculas y lo concatenamos con el resto
- **CapitalizeAllWords**: Llamamos a una función, que hace un `split` para dividir las palabras, luego capitalizamos y la volvemos a unir con un `join`

**2.- Ahora queremos una función que opere sobre un RANGO de un string**

Creamos una función que reciba como argumento un rango y retorne la concatenación del lado `izquierdo + el rango + el lado derecho`. Donde solo a lo que está en rango aplicamos la transformación, y a los lados derecho e izquierdo los retornamos sin modificación

```
public static string Transform(this string source, StringTransformation transformation, System.Range range)
{
    return source[..range.Start] + source[range].Transform(transformation) + source[range.End..];
}
```

**3.- El problema de `CapitalizeAllWords`**

Cuando el rango comienza en medio de una palabra, no se debe capitalizar. Para esto modificamos la función anterior, colocando unas condiciones:

- La transformación debe ser del tipo `CapitalizeAllWords`
- El inicio del rango debe ser mayor que cero, caso contrario estamos con el inicio de la palabra, y debe capitalizarse
- El inicio del rango NO debe coincidir con un espacio, ya que también significa que nos encontramos con un inicio de palabra.

```
public static string Transform(this string source, StringTransformation transformation, System.Range range)
{
    if(StringTransformation.CapitalizeAllWords == transformation && range.Start.Value > 0 && source[range.Start.Value]!=' ')
    {
        if(range.Start.Value > range.End.Value) return source;
        var start = range.Start.Value + 1;
        return source.Transform(transformation, start..range.End);
    }
    return source[..range.Start] + source[range].Transform(transformation) + source[range.End..];
}
```

Si se cumplen estas condiciones se vuelve a llamar la función recursivamente, cambiando el rango inicial al siguiente index. Es decir nos vamos moviendo hacia la derecha hasta encontrar un inicio de palabra y ese será nuestro nuevo rango

**4.- Código completo**

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Transform(this string source, StringTransformation transformation)
    {
        if (source.Length == 0) return source;
        return transformation switch
        {
            StringTransformation.LowerCase => source.ToLower(),
            StringTransformation.UpperCase => source.ToUpper(),
            StringTransformation.Normal => source,
            StringTransformation.Capitalize => char.ToUpper(source[0]) + source[1..],
            StringTransformation.CapitalizeAllWords => CapitalizeAllWords(source),
            _ => source
        };
    }

    public static string Transform(this string source, StringTransformation transformation, System.Range range)
    {
        if(StringTransformation.CapitalizeAllWords == transformation && range.Start.Value > 0 && source[range.Start.Value]!=' ')
        {
            if(range.Start.Value > range.End.Value) return source;
            var start = range.Start.Value + 1;
            return source.Transform(transformation, start..range.End);
        }
        return source[..range.Start] + source[range].Transform(transformation) + source[range.End..];
    }
     
    private static string CapitalizeAllWords(string sourse)
        => string.Join(" ", sourse.Split(" ").Select(a => a.Transform(StringTransformation.Capitalize)));

}
```

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, excelente explicación. Y +1 por el ingenio alternativo de emplear Linq, expresiones switch e indexación por rango. Con unos ajustes esta implementación me abre un gran abanico de posibilidades adicionales a mi idea original.